# Microsoft Excel 2003 Sequence numbering

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I am in need of working out how to have sequence numbering in the excel database I'm creating.
I am trying to have the following
001/15,
002/15,
003/15...

I am having no luck in getting this to work as it counting the last number "15".

If their some formula to have this working?

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Say A1 contains 001/15. In A2:

```
    =TEXT(LEFT(A1,3)+1,"000")&"/15"
```

Copy this down the column.

Note: Excel handles the text result of LEFT(A1,3) as a number based on the context.  For someone with a similar problem using a different spreadsheet, you may need to explicitly translate that result into a number to avoid an error.  You would use this:

```
    =TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))+1,"000")&"/15"
```